# Calling website classes from another website hosted in IIS

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I have 2 websites ( under the same directory ) hosted in IIS  , say site 1 (containing class siteClass.CreateUser) , say site 2 ( Login class ) . Currently in Site2 Solution, I have added project reference to Site 1 and called the SiteClass.CreateUser method from Login Class . Is this the right way to do ? My rationale was since both site exists under the same parent directory and hosted in IIS , I thought its better to create a project reference instead of creating a service reference ? Is this okay ?

Answer (score 0):

If your sites have the same logic it is better to defined it as the common logic layer. It will contain class `siteClass` and other classes (interfaces, etc) which is used in common.

Both your site should reference this layer by using project reference. It is better for performance too.

Service reference should use if you are going to build service-oriented architectur in general. For example, if your service from site1 will have more than one (site2) client or if you want to distribute autonomy services among different servers.

Comment: Thanks Sir Hally , I appreciate your response. I have just understood that I need to create a web reference for the above problem ( as site 1 and site 2 can be hosted on different environments). But I am not sure if it should be a web reference or service reference. The Create user is defined as wcf operartion contract. Since the consumer is .net 3.5 , is it okay to define a service reference ? If yes , how should I make it dynamic for deployment purpose. If I add a service reference , i do not see any endpoint configuration etc in web.config file.

Comment: I've understood your problem. It depends on your goals: if you are sure, that these sites will be work in common all time and if you want to maximaze the speed of the work, the project reference is the better choise. But your sites won't be independent (according to SOA principles).
If you want to make flexible solution with two completly independent sites, the service reference is better. But it decrease your speed.